# Why weekdays returns the week day in German?

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and doing the following returns the day of the week in German .. why?

```
library(lubridate)
ts <- c(1129503178, 850121164, 848329742, 1199772925, 1114229246)
weekdays(as_datetime(ts))
[1] "Sonntag"  "Montag"   "Montag"   "Dienstag" "Samstag"
```

How can I change it to either English or a number for each week day?

**UPDATE** doing `sessionInfo()` yields the following result:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_CH.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_CH.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=de_CH.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_CH.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah just doing the following partially solves the issue and now the days of the week show in US English:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8")
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"
```

Now the OP outputs:

```
 > weekdays(as_datetime(ts))
 [1] "Sunday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Tuesday"  "Saturday"
```

However, I'd prefer a numeric output e.g. "Sunday" -> 1, "Monday" -> 2 etc.

Comment: Maybe something like `as.POSIXlt(lubridate::as_datetime(ts))$wday` ?

Comment: You could just stay with `lubridate` too :  `lubridate::wday(lubridate::as_datetime(ts))` which would give Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7